# Classic ASP with Server.CreateObject on Azure Web apps

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, azure-web-app-service

I have a classic ASP application that uses a custom written VB6 COM object (.dll) through `Server.CreateObject`.

I can deploy and run classic ASP (.asp) in an Azure web app, but I'm not sure how to get to the point where I can use my VB6 COM object.

Uploading the .dll to the web folder and using `Server.CreateObject` just results in the expected:

```
 An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.
```

Is it possible to use your own custom .dlls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible using Web Apps.  Using Virtual Machines, you have more control and you'll be able to register your COM DLL.

Comment: Would Registration-Free COM work with an Azure Web App?